# Flask app using Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB API connection error

Tags: mongodb, azure, flask

I am build a Flask app using Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB API and I am having a connection error in the following lines. I am following this tut: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/CosmosDB-Flask-Mongo-Sample

I am getting error in the following line:

```
client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:10250/?ssl=true")
```

When I run the flask server, I get this error: pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. Can anyone resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally followed the [tut](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/CosmosDB-Flask-Mongo-Sample) you provided and it works fine for me.

Run LOG:

[image]

View URL:

[image]

Based on the error:

> pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: [WinError 10061] No connection could
>   be made because the target machine actively refused it.

It seems that you didn't open COSMOS DB emulator,please check the status of it.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your comment! I got it, had a small bug in the url!

Comment: @YuneebAzam Cheers! You could mark the answer for others' reference,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the emulator with the command from the cmd:

```
> cd "C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator"
> .\CosmosDB.Emulator.exe /EnableMongoDbEndpoint
```

Comment: How your answer will help OP?

Comment: I was getting the same error since I was starting the Cosmos DB Emulator with double cliking the icon and it seems that the mongodb endpoint was not enabled